# update single row in Android cursor

Tags: android, performance, cursor

In my app I use ListView with CursorAdapter. When some data in some row of database is changed, I recreate cursor for CursorAdapter.

This process is expensive. Is there any way to update just needed rows in Cursor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no better approach. But CursorAdapter loads only those items that are visible.

Answer (score 0):

No. Although we may wish to look at `MatrixCursor` and see if it may of some use to you.